# Google Drive API - How to handle multithreading and folder creation right?

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, google-cloud-platform, drive

I have an application which is running a pub/sub job every couple minutes.

Whenever the application realizes a folder do not exists in Google Drive it creates the hierarchy correctly. I had to multi-thread this application in order to meet customer demands, and now multiple folders are being created. I need a logic solution here, best practice or maybe a API insight in order to solve this issue.

Here's a snippet of the actual code:

```
if not output_folder:
    output_folder = drive_handler.create_folder_hierarchy  
                   (process_id, mail.get_date(), product, activity, team_drive_id)
    log_handler.log_hierarchy_created(mail, process_id)

def create_folder(self, name, team_drive_id, parent):
    properties = self.get_properties(parent)
    fields = 'kind, id, name, mimeType, parents, properties'
    body = {"name": name,
            "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder",
            "parents": [parent],
            "teamDriveId": team_drive_id,
            "properties": properties}
    folder = self.service.files().create(body=body, supportsTeamDrives=True, fields=fields).execute()
    return folder
```

I've tried time.sleep(), cron jobs on app engine, but I didn't feel like those were the best way to do this.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Could you elaborate? Did it work single threaded?  There are several ways how this can go wrong.  One of them is that you first check for non-existence of a directory and then start creating them. This can be a race condition without locks, and two threads pass the "directory does not exist" check and both proceed to directory creation. The other is that you assume google API is thread safe, which it is not.  https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/thread_safety

Comment: @Hannu My problem is multiple folder creation, because every thread is checking at the same time for folder existence (which is returning false) and then doing creation. I need a idea here in order to run it nice.

Answer (score 1):

You need a global lock across your threads and then make sure directory checking and creation happen in the same context:

from threading import Lock

```
# Global variable
foo = Lock()

def check_create():
    with foo:
        # Check if directory exists
        # Create if it does not
    return folder
```

This pseudocode example shows the idea.  Now checking and creation happen within the same context and only one thread can have the lock.

Comment: This can be improved a bit by checking outside the lock as well, otherwise every single request will have to acquire the lock, rather than just the requests that are competing to create the folder the first time.